# Multiplication of two floating point 2-d arrays

Tags: mips

I have two 3x3 floating point arrays. I stored them as two 1D arrays and wrote the following code to multiply them( here, s3 is the output matrix):-
 MULTIP1:
      li $t8,4
                            # $s7 has address of array s2 and $s4 has address of array arr
      la $t9,s3
      li $t1,0
      li $t2,1
      li $t3,0
      li $t4,1

```
LOOP1:
 beq $t4,$t8,MULTIP2    #multip2 is the next segment of program
 li $t2,1
ENTER1:
beq $t2,$t8,UP1
li $t0,1
LOOP2:
  beq $t0,$t8,UP2
ENTER2:
  lwc1 $f22,0($s7)
  lwc1 $f24,0($s4)
  mul.s $f8,$f22,$f24
  add.s $f10,$f10,$f8
  swc1 $f10,0($t9)

  addi $s7,$s7,4
  addi $s4,$s4,12
  addi $t0,$t0,1
  j LOOP2
UP2:
  l.s  $f10,zero
  addi $t9,$t9,4
  addi $t1,$t1,4     #update column of second matrix
  la $s7,s2
  add $s7,$s7,$t3
  la $s4,arr
  add $s4,$s4,$t1
  addi $t2,$t2,1
  j ENTER1
UP1:

  addi $t3,$t3,12
  la   $s7,s2
  add  $s7,$s7,$t3  #update row of first matrix
  la   $s4,arr
  addi $t4,$t4,1
  j LOOP1
```

This code gives only the first row of the expected output matrix correctly... The rest is messed up.... Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

- Is this not just the dot product of two 3x3 matrices?
- The dot product of 2 3x3 matrices results in a 3x3 matrix
- Assume 2 3x3 matrices: A and B.
- Matrix C the product where C = AB as follows:

  A = [a11, a12, a13]
      [a21, a22, a23]
      [a31, a32, a33]

  B = [b11, b12, b13]
      [b21, b22, b23]
      [b31, b32, b33]

  C = [c11, c12, c13]
      [c21, c22, c23]
      [c31, c32, c33]

  c11 = a11*b11+a12*b21+a13*b31
  c12 = a11*b12+a12*b22+a13*b23
  c13 = a11*b13+a12*b23+a13*b32
  c21 = a21*b11+a22*b21+a23*b31
  c22 = a21*b12+a22*b22+a23*b32
  c23 = a21*b13+a22*b23+a23*b33
  c31 = a31*b11+a32*b21+a33*b31
  c32 = a31*b12+b32*b22+a33*b32
  c33 = a31*b13+a32*b23+a33*b33

Comment: That's correct... And the code gives the correct answer for c11,c12 and c13 but not the rest...